# Chosen - Binding to change event after Chosen is applied to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am currently using the [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin, and it is working well. Currently, I can bind to Chosen's change event like so:

```
$('#the_selector').chosen().change( ... );
```

And this works fine. I have encountered a case, however, where I need to bind to the change event after Chosen has already been applied to the select. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to bind to the event using:

```
$('#the_selector').on('change', function(){
    Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it uses the standard change event with some params as below

```
  $('.PayeeID').on('change', function (evt, params) {

     var selectedValue = params['selected']
     dosomthing(selectedValue);
}
```

params ==> has the selected value  if it is single select